# Multiline textview in Tablelayout moving the textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have a table layout with this textView:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="line1 \nline2"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />
```

But the textview shifts downwards.  I'd like it to simply be like the others, but with 2 lines of text, centered in the textView.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add `layout_gravity` to `center` with two line `TextView` like below:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="line1 \nline2"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />
```

Comment: @microflakes, Did you try that? If it will help you then accept the answer and hit upvote. Thanks